# Scrolling an Image with ImageView iOS

Tags: ios, imageview

I'm trying to make an app for a restaurant and the to display the food menu as a scrollable image. The image is pulled form a config file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // back button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 46.0f, 28.0f);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
    [customBarItem release];


    [self setTitle:[menu objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [scrollView2 setScrollEnabled:YES];

    NSString *imageName = [menu objectForKey:@"imageName"];
    if (![imageName isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        [imageView setImage:image];
        [scrollView2 addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
    [textView setText:[menu objectForKey:@"description"]];
}
```

As of now the image doesn't scroll, but appears as a static image. Could anyone please help me modify this code so the user can vertically scroll the image.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the frame and content size of your scroll view set to?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `UIScrollView`and add the `UIImageView` as subview of the contentView.
And then set the contentsize of the scrollview as the imageviews size.

```
[imageView setImage:image];
[scrollView2.contentView addSubview:imageView];
[scrollView2  setContentSize:image.frame.size];
[imageView release];
```

have no Mac to test at the moment but that should work.

Comment: I added it as    

 [scrollView2 addSubview:imageView]; 



but it still is static. Could you please show me how the modification is. I'm new to iOS development actually. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just tried your code :). But scrollview2.contentview is not a valid code. It gives me an error. Also, Image.Frame.size isn't valid either. I made a few modifications and this is how it looks now, still doesn't work. 

` NSString *imageName = [menu objectForKey:@"imageName"];
    if (![imageName isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage  imageNamed:imageName];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        [scrollView2 addSubview:imageView];
        [scrollView2  setContentSize:image.size];
        [imageView release];
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

I agree mostly with what Seega wrote. Your imageView must be subview of a scrollView. Then, don't forget to set the scrollView's contentSize & the minimum&maximumZoomScale & and the imageView's frame:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);

self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = // some number between 0 and 1, default is 1, so no zoom
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = // some number larger than 1, default is 1, so no zoom
self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1 // starting zoom scale
```

A nice place to put this code is in

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{}
```

Thus it will be executed everytime the view appears & also whenever the device is rotated.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply. I actually tried putting in that code. But I'm getting a few code errors. Here's a screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/a/img843/1345/screenshot20120916at449.png

could you please take a look at it and help :)